# How to create more space for figure numbers in the list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I am making a list of figures where numbering is increasing for each chapter and paragraph: so I get something like Figure 4.4.1, etc. I noticed that in my output the spacing after the numbers is not enough. How do I increase it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can use one of the dedicated packages, say `titletoc` (which comes with `titlesec`) or `tocloft`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using one of the "standard" LaTeX document classes (`article`, `report`, or `book`) or a document class that's built on one of these classes, I suggest you load the [tocloft](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package and issue the instruction

```
\cftsetindents{figure}{0pt}{3.5em}
```

in the preamble. (You're obviously free to modify the choice `3.5em` to suit your needs.)

---

A full MWE (mininum working example) and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\cftsetindents{figure}{0pt}{3.5em}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{4} % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{4}
\setcounter{figure}{10}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\caption{Linear elastic physics domain}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Fixed domain}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Fluid-structure interaction boundaries}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Plane of symmetry}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Adiabatic pressure at the channel inlet}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```